# Any way to get hwid without showing console in python?

Tags: python, console, subprocess, pyinstaller

I want to built an app with **pyinstaller** and implement **HWID** lock in it, and the best way to do it I found so far is:

```py
hwid = subprocess.Popen('wmic csproduct get uuid', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
```

so I did this

```py
import subprocess
import PySimpleGUIQt as Sg

hw_id = str(subprocess.Popen('wmic csproduct get uuid', shell=True,
                             stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]).split('\\r\\n')[1].strip('\\r').strip()

layout = [[Sg.Text(hw_id)]]
window = Sg.Window('test', layout)
while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event is None:
        break
```

And  it works when I compile [include console]: `pyinstaller --onefile testt.py`

But If I don't include console while compiling: `pyinstaller --onefile --windowed testt.py`

it throws an error

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testt.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "subprocess.py", line 829, in __init__
  File "subprocess.py", line 1252, in _get_handles
OSError: [WinError 6] The handle is invalid
```

I thought a way but IDK how to do it, that is detach the process and somehow get the output,

I also don't know if it is possible with `os` or `sys`.

Also don't wanna use `uuid` module, as it's value changes.

`os.popen` doesn't work same issue

Comment: @BoarGules um how?? I'm very new to python and new to coding, 
wait aren't I using `Popen.communicate()` ??
`hwid = subprocess.Popen('wmic csproduct get uuid', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]`

Comment: Umm, good point. Let me look again. But the problem is `subprocess.PIPE`, which in a windowed application doesn't exist.

Comment: @BoarGules Well you can do this,